# What purpose does the "Chat With An Expert" bot serve on this site?

Tags: support

Why is a 'bot suddenly bothering me when I sit at a question page now?  I played with it for 2-3 minutes, and it seems to me it's nothing more than a playtoy...

[image]

Comment: I am too curious to know if this is like knowledge in SF that scraps through existing answers and tries to provide a solution/ a fancy chat to motivate depressed coders?

Comment: It 100% reminds me of a module for MajorBBS/Worldgroup (way back in the day) called "The Doctor".  It took comments addressed to it in Teleconference and redirected something back to the sender, as a question or sometimes as a comment.  "Doctor, why is the sky blue?" "Anthony, I sometimes wonder why the sky is blue" etc...  :-P

Comment: Check the date on the calendar.

Comment: Oh F___ me.   Wow.  I actually got "got".  (sigh)

Comment: That is just too good :)

Comment: Just so you know, i had a very meaningful conversation with that expert.

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert